# React-navigation with a button in header

Tags: react-native, redirect, button, react-navigation

I'am trying to redirect to a profile page from a button in the header with `react-navigation`.

Here's what the `createStackNavigator` :

```
const NavigationApp = createStackNavigator({
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreenContainer },
    Application: { 
        screen: Application,  
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Title",
            headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000",
        }, 
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerRight: (
          <HeaderScreenContainer/>
        ), 
      },
    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Application"
});
const App = createAppContainer(NavigationApp);
export default App;
```

Here's my screen container for the header :

```
export default class HeaderScreenContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<HeaderScreen profile={this.handleProfile.bind(this)} />);
    }

    handleProfile() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
    }
}
```

This is the button that I am rendering in header and that is supposed to redirect to the profile page.

```
export default class HeaderScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Button onPress={() => this.props.profile()}>
                <Text>Profile</Text>    
            </Button>
        )
    }
}
```

I am constantly getting the error : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')`.
Actually it's supposed to redirect to the profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to wrap your `HeaderScreenContainer` in the [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html) HOC like this...

```
class HeaderScreenContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<HeaderScreen profile={this.handleProfile.bind(this)} />);
    }

    handleProfile() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
    }
}

export default withNavigation(HeaderScreenContainer)
```